# Experience letter or success story

Tags: resume, career-development, references, recommendation-letter

I was working as a solution architect and consultant for a project in one of largest banks in the country through one of the international IT consultancy companies. My project allocation contact ended few days ago. I asked the product owner in client side if I could have an experience certificate or success story for the project that I worked for, which he didn't mind to give. He asked me to prepare it and he will sign it.

I was one of the first leads for the project I worked on. After 10 months, I left the project in a stable working state. Even though lots of work still needed, and development will go for a long way ahead, but it is considered a successful project for all parties and stakeholders.

I'd like to know, what is the best type of letter I can get: experience letter or success story? and what can I include in that certificate? shall I focus on the project or on my role within that project?

Comment: What country are you employed in? Advice will vary based upon geography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually your direct employer who provides you the experience certificate.

What you can ask of your client, is a testimonial, or a performance certificate, which you can mention in your CV. Remember, this should not include any confidential information for the client (like system details, unique IPs etc). Focus more on your performance and contributions areas, because it's your performance certificate.